# ProbabilityDistribution PDF on boundary points

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

I would like to evaluate the PDF of a custom `ProbabilityDistribution` at the min and max values. However, `PDF[...]` returns 0 at the boundary conditions. Is there an elegant way to prevent this? Example:

```
dst = ProbabilityDistribution[2 x, {x, 0, 1}];
PDF[dst, 0.99999] (* = 1.99998 *)
PDF[dst, 1] (* = 0 *) (* I would like this to return 2 *)
```

The [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) say that

> the pdf is taken to be zero for $x < x_{min}$ and $x > x_{max}$

It seems inconsistent that the PDF is forced to zero at $x = x_{max}$.

Comment: It's either a bug in the definition or incorrect documentation. Implementation wise, it is definitely defined only for $x_{min}<x<x_{max}$ and not for $x_{min}\le x\le x_{max}$. For example, see what this gives you: `PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[f, {x, 0, 1}], x]`

Comment: Does it have impact on any of your calculations? I don't think it will matter at all, so why care? `Plot[PDF[dst, x], {x, -1, 2},  ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]`does exactly what you would expect. Same for `Integrate[PDF[dst, x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`

Comment: Knowing of this issue you can use e.g. `Limit[PDF[dst, x], x -> 1 , Direction -> 1]` and `Limit[PDF[dst, x], x -> 0 , Direction -> -1]` to get  `2` or `0` respectively.

Comment: Side note: the PDF you used in ProbabilityDistribution is not normalized.  This is known to cause various functions to silently return incorrect results.